# Leaflet add custom layer - url template \ Custom GetTileUrl

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

How can I modify coordinates and zoom (x,y,z) in Tile Layer Url 
[URL template documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayerplate)

Example:

```
var mm = L.tileLayer('http://maps.domain.com/2.0/navitms.fcgi?t={x},{y},{z}', {});
```

{x},{y},{z} transform with my mathematical function

Answer (score 0):

You could make new variables x0, y0 and z0 (defined with whatever formula you want) in leaflet's getTileUrl function and call on {x0},{y0},{z0} instead of {x},{y},{z} for this particular layer.